# Displaying dynamic information on SAP Fiori Launchpad tile (SCP portal services)

Tags: sapui5, portal, sap-fiori, sap-cloud-platform

I want to create a tile showing dynamic information on tile using SAP Cloud Platform portal services. I am unable to display all information on custom tile using odata service.

Below is the image of what i want to achieve:
[image]

Methods we tried:

1. Create a dynamic tile on fiori launchpad.

Reference :

https://blogs.sap.com/2017/02/07/dynamic-fiori-launchpad-tile-explained/

We were only able to display number using this method.

Output we achieved:

[image]

Odata Structure:

[image]

Portal service launchpad cockpit:

[image]

2. Create a custom tile on fiori launchpad:

We created a custom tile using custom app launcher.

And tried to call odata using read function in Init() function.

Problem we are facing is, the odata gets called while running the application using configuration ‘Run as SAP Fiori Launchpad Sandbox’ and the number and info are displayed.

But when we deploy the same app to launchpad, the Init() function gets triggered, but odata is not getting called.

Output:

[image]

Portal service launchpad cockpit:

[image]

Please guide on how to display dynamic information on custom tile.

Comment: Have you seen this blog already  https://blogs.sap.com/2017/01/25/dynamic-tile-in-sap-webide/ ?
It seems pretty similar to your approach.